# How to hide toolbar in CKEditor inline

Tags: ckeditor

I have an application that needs the inline CKEditor but without toolbar. For the inline CKEditor part I have:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('editable', {on: {
    instanceReady: function() {periodic();}
}});

var periodic = (function() {
    var data, oldData;
    return function() {
        if ((data = editor.getData()) !== oldData) {
            oldData = data;
            $.post("update.php", {txt:data});
        }
        setTimeout(periodic, 1000);
    };
})();
```

Then for the toolbar hiding part I found this: [CKEditor 4 Inline: How to hide toolbar on demand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877948/ckeditor-4-inline-how-to-hide-toolbar-on-demand)

```
//Whenever CKEditor loses focus, We will hide the corresponding toolbar DIV.
function hideToolBarDiv(event) {
   // Select the correct toolbar DIV and hide it.
   //'event.editor.name' returns the name of the DIV receiving focus.
   $('#'+event.editor.name+'TBdiv').hide();
}
```

Problem is that I have no clue how to combine these two together :) I appreciate for any hint. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use CKEditor without a toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611386/can-i-use-ckeditor-without-a-toolbar)

Comment: I updated my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611386/can-i-use-ckeditor-without-a-toolbar explaining that Advanced Content Filter is not configured without toolbar, so you need to do this manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another link that seems to solve my problem: [Can I use CKEditor without a toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611386/can-i-use-ckeditor-without-a-toolbar)
The script seems to be working alright though I am still not sure if it is a correct way to do it:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('editable', {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar',
    allowedContent: 'p h1 h2 strong em; a[!href]; img[!src,width,height]'
    on: {instanceReady: function() {periodic();}}
});

var periodic = (function() {
    var data, oldData;
    return function() {
        if ((data = editor.getData()) !== oldData) {
            oldData = data;
            $.post("update.php", {txt:data});
        }
        setTimeout(periodic, 1000);
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes, I have done it in two ways:

**1) Using the `removePlugins` option and just remove the toolbar:**

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'textarea', {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar'
} );
```

here, you can also use `allowedContent` to allow the contents for ACF

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar',
    allowedContent: 'p h1 h2 strong em; a[!href]; img[!src,width,height];'
} );
```

**2) Using CSS - Not the standard approach: (little tricky)**

Just make css to `display:none` the toolbar, like

```
.cke_inner {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it will help someone.